# Best way to navigate to a nested destination

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

The app I'm currently working on has many fragments with nested menus and a really messy navigation. I thought Navigation with nested nav graphs is a natural solution and migrated a small portion of the app. I also need to support search functionality which involves navigating directly from root graph to a nested destination. But according to [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs).

> Destinations outside of the nested graph, such as those on the root graph, access the nested graph only through its start destination.

Is there an elegant hack for this?

I think its a pretty common pattern so is there a better way to implement it with Navigation AAC?

Comment: i posted a question like this but nobody answered :(

https://stackoverflow.com/q/60025414/5829679